# How would I create a Python web server that downloads a file on any GET request?

Tags: python, file, http, web, webserver

I am attempting to create an easy solution to file sharing across computers in my local network. I used to execute `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in bash whenever I wanted to share a directory, but I wanted a way to share only one specific file. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how I might create a web server, and then have it download a file for each GET request. For example, someone on my network could go to my IP and have the file download.

P.S. What would be even cooler is if there was a way to password protect a file! Also, I have Python 2.7.2, if that matters. Anyway, As you have probably noticed, I know almost nothing about Python, but I learn by example so I am hoping this will help me some as well.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try following:

```
try:
    import http.server as BaseHTTPServer  # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    import BaseHTTPServer  # Python 2.x
import os
import shutil
import sys

FILEPATH = sys.argv[1] if sys.argv[1:] else __file__

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        with open(FILEPATH, 'rb') as f:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-Type", 'application/octet-stream')
            self.send_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(FILEPATH)))
            fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs.st_size))
            self.end_headers()
            shutil.copyfileobj(f, self.wfile)

def test(HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,
         ServerClass=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
         protocol="HTTP/1.0"):
    if sys.argv[2:]:
        port = int(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        port = 8000
    server_address = ('', port)

    HandlerClass.protocol_version = protocol
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, HandlerClass)

    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print("Serving HTTP on {0[0]} port {0[1]} ... {1}".format(sa, FILEPATH))
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Usage: `python script_path [filepath_to_serve [port]]`

**UPDATE** code works for Python 2.x / 3.x

Comment: Thanks, this worked more than perfectly! Would you mind if I used this for an app I am working on?

Comment: @russellsayshi, I don't mind. I refered to `SimpleHTTPServer.py` source code.

Comment: Actually, just noticed something. I can connect to the server from my computer, but others on my network cannot... when I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` as I did before, it workes perfectly, and still does. Any ideas?

Comment: @russellsayshi, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: `''` was used (represents INADDR_ANY) for bind; so it should accept any connection.

Comment: @russellsayshi, After you run the script, check the output of `netstat -an | grep :8000` (`netstat -an | findstr :8000` if you use Windows).  It should print line similar to `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`.

Comment: When I do `netstat -an | grep :8000` it doesn't work, however `netstat -an | grep 8000` (without the colon) delivers `tcp4       0      0  *.8000                 *.*                    LISTEN` when the server is running.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have it stop the server after a download, so the file can only be downloaded once? I had it on `handle_request()` instead of `serve_forever()`, and that caused a problem because some browsers do a GET request for the favicon before loading a page.

Comment: If possible, Can you give the python 3.x version of this code.

Comment: thanks this piece of code, saved a lot of time for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SasukeUchiha, Replace all occurences of `BaseHTTPServer` with `http.server`. And adjust `print` statement to be a function call.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha, I updated the code to work both on Python 2/3.